# Visual studio find & replace with regex, replace space with underscore

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

I have a large list of text in c# that in want to use as an enum list.
For example:

```
Zone Status Message
Zones Snapshot Message
Partition Status Message
Partitions Snapshot Message
Supported transition message flags
System Status Message
X-10 Message Received
Log Event Message
Keypad Message Received
```

Now I want to use the find and replace dialog in visual studio to add underscores in all the words instead of a space, 
for example

```
Zone_Status_Message
Zones_Snapshot_Message
```

How can I achieve this using regex or wildcard? 
This would really save me a lot of time.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The words can also have spaces and the front and back, due to a poorly formatted source document where I get the text from. So the underscore should only be added when the space is between 2 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS 2010, to replace a space between alphanumeric characters you could use

**Find What**   `{:a} {:a}`
**Replace With**  `\1_\2`

Make sure `Use Regular expressions` is checked.

**Replace All**

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match spaces between alphanumeric words, search for `> <` and replace all with `_`.

In VS regexes (until version 2010), `>` means "the position at the end of a word" and `<` means "the position at the start of a word".

In VS 2012 and up, that regex could be written as `\b \b`.

Comment: I copy the words from another document, so they aren't really formatted properly. Doing this also adds underscores to the front and back of a word sometimes.

Comment: @just8laze: Then you need to edit your question to reflect this. Your question doesn't warrant a regex yet. And without knowing all the specific constraints you're under, it's impossible to suggest a working regex. Don't oversimplify your problem, or you'll get answers that only work in simple cases...